# How to calculate $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,-1)} \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^3 + y^3}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,-1)} \frac{x^2 - y^2}{x^3 + y^3}$$

By approaching along x = 1 or y = -1 and using L'Hopitals rule, I can establish that if the limit does exist, then it is $\frac{2}{3}$.

This matches the result given by Wolfram Alpha and is consistent with a 3D graph of the function.

However I am struggling to prove that this limit exists along all approach paths.

I have tried $x = -y$ and the Sandwich Theorem but still seem no closer to a general proof.

Can you give me a hint for to the correct method for proving that this limit exists?

Comment: cubic expansion will remove the singularity in the denominator.

Comment: @corbah Right again. I'll remove both comments above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,-1)}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^3+y^3}&=\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,-1)}\frac{(x+y)(x-y)}{(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)}\\
&=\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,-1)}\frac{x-y}{x^2-xy+y^2}\\
&=\frac{1-(-1)}{1-1\cdot(-1)+1}\\
&=\frac{2}{3}
\end{align}

Comment: That's awesome - I didn't see it could be factorized like that, thanks!

Comment: NOTE: This works as long as the function is constrained to $x \ne -y$